# Will changing app shapes be affected by themes?

Tags: developer-options, themes

I have just desovered 'developer mode' and there is an option to change the app shape. But I have a theme installed on my phone and I don't know if me having a theme will not let the shape change or will make my theme disable so the app shape can change? Basically can I have a theme enabled and still change my app shape?

Answer (score 1):

**Icon Shapes**

Home screen icon shape changing is the feature by android. It was first introduced in Android 8.0 Oreo. Later, in Android 9.0 Pie and Android 10 Q, more shapes are added. Shapes include Square, circle(default),squircle,teardrop etc.

**Themes**

Theme is a feature provided by some manufacturers(Samsung, Xiaomi, Oneplus, Realme etc). Theme changes complete look and feel of devices by its color,icon styles, positioning etc.

Note: I am using stock android, I don't know whether manufacturers provide icon shape changing on their theme app.

Comment: (Sorry for the off) Welcome in the 2k club! Please review more - I think the site strongly needs more VLQ + suggested edit reviewers.